# Elementor, How to translate Text based on API response?

Tags: jquery, css, translation, elementor

I am creating a table, and fill the data through API.

there are some texts need to be translated, to my client’s language, here is an example

if the response is “00” then it means “Ok”
but if “01” means “Harmful”
while “02” means ”Dancer”, and so

I put the Code in container and the description in another container because of design.

any advice?

I’ve tried to use jQuery to hide all containers and display the matched one with CSS but i failed because I am new with it.

Answer (score 0):

when you want to display answer, you can use id or class of these containers to put values like:

```
var description = "";

if(code == "00"){
   description = "OK";
}

$(".code_container").append("<span>"+code+"</span>");
$(".descript_container").append("<span>"+description+"</span>");
```